# Decode a piece of Bitmap on Android

Tags: android, out-of-memory, decode, android-bitmap

I have an `OutOfMemoryError` working with Android.
I have a 1000x1000 bitmap with 10 images of a sprite. (each image is 100x100)

I can load only a portion (100x100) bitmap?

`BitmapFactory.decodeResource()` produces `OutOfMemoryError` because I have to load the entire bitmap. And I only need a 100x100.

Comment: been asked several times

Comment: Break your sprite into smaller part.

Comment: (nota: the accepted answer is not complete, the second answer should be more correct)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [BitmapRegionDecoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html)

Example

```
BitmapRegionDecoder decoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(myStream, false);
Bitmap region = decoder.decodeRegion(new Rect(100, 100, 100, 100), null);
```